# How to config STAF on macosx

Tags: python, macos

I have installed a STAF in macosx , but there is a document say how to config it, and i use 
`./startSTAFProc.sh` to run the staf, and then `staf local ping ping`, it shows no command staf found.
Any ideas about staf on macosx

Comment: check if STAF path is added to envirnment if not, add it

Comment: @avasal, how to add the STAF path to environment, i try ./STAFEnv.sh but nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful 
 http://staf.sourceforge.net/current/STAFInstall.pdf

**PATH** : must contain the `STAF` bin directory in order to start `STAFProc` (e.g. `/Library/staf/bin`).

**DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH** : must contain the `STAF` lib directory (e.g.
    `/Library/staf/lib`), unless you allowed softlinks to be installed in
    the default system directories

**CLASSPATH**: must contain the `JSTAF.jar` file (e.g.
    `/Library/staf/lib/JSTAF.jar`). `JSTAF.jar` contains the `STAF Java APIs`
    to communicate with `STAF` from Java programs and is also required to
    register `STAF` services written in Java.

**STAFCONVDIR**: must be set to the `STAF` codepage directory if you did
    not install `STAF` in the default target directory (e.g.
    `/Library/staf`).

**STAFCODEPAGE**: must be set on systems which do not return a valid
    value from `nl_langinfo(CODESET)` (specifically if that call returns
    NULL or the empty string). The value of this variable should contain
    the codepage being used by the system. See c`odepage/alias.txt` for
    valid values. If you are unsure, use `LATIN_1`